# How to know which field from a table receives a variable?

Tags: sapb1

I'm starting with SAPB1 and when I'm trying to set my file to import products to the inventory I've a field (select list) that's need to be filled, but I can't find what and where it is stored since on system information shows "form=150 pane=6  variable=82".

I still have no access to the development tools. How can I find where's stored, and what data is in the variable depending on the selected choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the *Batch number / Serial number* combo box?
I could not find the actual variable in the OITM table.

But you can see that:

1. If the item is managed by *Batch number*, the field `OITM.ManBtchNum` = Y.
2. If it is *Serial number* managed, the field `OITM.ManSerNum` = Y.

Hope it helps.